# Differential in Ito's formula and little o notation

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations, quadratic-variation

Let $Z_\pi$ be the continuous semimartingale defined by $$d(\log Z_\pi(t)) = \gamma(t) dt + \sum_{j=1}^n a_j(t) dW_j(t) $$ where $W_j, j =1, ..., n$ is a standard $n$-dimensional Brownian motion and $$\int_0^t |\gamma(s)| + |a_j(s)|^2 ds < \infty \quad \forall t \ge 0 \text{ a.s.}$$  Why is the following true?

[image]

Ignore the part about the change in weights for my question (it is not relevant - this passage is from *Stochastic Portfolio Theory*, p. 130 by Fernholz).  I know that regarding Ito's formula, we have $$Z_\pi^2(t+dt) - Z_\pi^2(t) = \int_t^{t+dt}2Z_\pi(s)dZ_\pi(s) + \int_t^{t+dt}d \langle Z_\pi \rangle_s$$ and that the sum of the squares over a partition of $[0,t]$ and $[0, t+dt]$ will converge to the quadratic variation, but how do we justify the little $o(dt)$  in each case? I do not see how to get here from Ito.

---

If I'm not mistaken, this would be equivalent to showing $$\int_t^{t+dt} Z_\pi(s) dZ_\pi(s) = Z_\pi(t) (Z_\pi(t+dt) - Z_\pi(t)) + o(dt)$$ and I have no idea how the $o(dt)$ enters here either.

---

Thanks for any help you can give here!

Comment: Ito gives $d(Z^2)=2ZdZ+(dZ)^2$ directly. I don't know why the author added $o(dt)$ as here $o(dt)\equiv0$.

Comment: I agree.  But then I'm not sure why we can say $$\int_t^{t+dt} \bigg( Z(s) - Z(t) \bigg) dZ(s)  = o(dt)$$ from which we could conclude using Ito's formula, which is obviously what I'm seeking help on.

Comment: Summarizing comments from the other question (thanks for the feedback! but I'm still putting it here for record) : $M_t^2 - \langle M_t \rangle$ is a local martingale. Thus, one would expect that $M_t^2 - \langle M_t \rangle$ is a quantity that is kind of well controlled. Indeed, every local martingale is a Brownian time change, therefore one would expect that $M_t^2$ and $\langle M_t \rangle$ decay roughly with the same order as $t \to 0$. Furthermore, any counterexample to a statement about the decay rates is then suitably searched for by using time changes of BM, as in that answer.

Comment: Coming to this question (which I had a look at, as a result of the other) : I actually don't see the definition of $(dZ_t)^2$ anywhere in the text! I was going all around looking for what this actually means. I know what it means from a "Ito rule" standpoint, but I was wondering if the book had a a different interpretation for it. Whatever it is, reading the source didn't give me much comfort. I'll go through the whole thing again.

Comment: As far as I understand,$(dZ_t)^2 = (Z(t+dt) - Z(t))^2$ so we just take the discrete difference. As noted in the first comment, that makes the $o(dt)$ term in the first line a bit redundant (so maybe this interpretation is wrong, but indeed you're right the book does not define it at all).

Comment: As for trying to show$$\begin{aligned} \int_t^{t+dt} \Big(Z(t) - Z(s) \Big) dZ(s) = \int_t^{t+dt} & \Big(Z(t) - Z(s) \Big) Z(s) \left( \gamma(s) + \frac{1}{2} \|a(s) \|^2 \right) ds \\ & + \int_t^{t+dt} \Big(Z(t) - Z(s) \Big) \sum_{i=1}^n a_i(s) dW_i(s) = o(dt) \end{aligned}$$it will suffice to show the local martingale term is $o(dt)$ since the FV term is clearly $o(dt)$.  This is where the motivation comes in from the last question, since the QV is clearly $o(dt)$.  In fact, it's $o(dt^2)$, which is where one of your earlier ideas might be fruitful.

Comment: @qp212223 Your second comment makes sense. As for the first, I'm just wondering but completely clueless about it : you ignored some changes in weights. I hope those changes in weights aren't leading to a non-trivial $o(dt)$ term, right? I mean, they should not , but I'm just confirming that $o(dt)$ on the first line should be zero even with that change of weights applied. The Ito rule stays the same so my guess is that nothing changes, but I thought I'd just bring this up in case.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon You're right that nothing changes (at least as far as I can understand) - the notation for $Z_\pi$ is just to emphasize the entrance of $\pi(t)$ terms in the $\gamma(t)$ and $a_i(t)$, which I have (perhaps unwisely) omitted for the sake of limiting notation.  The Ito rule doesn't change since all of this variation is captured in the change in $t$.  So, under the interpretation that $dZ$ is a discrete difference , the $o(dt)$ term in the first line should indeed be $0$.

Comment: The agonizing part is that a Holder continuity argument doesn't work: the local martingale term (call it $M$) may be written as $M_t = B_{\langle M \rangle_t}$ for some Brownian motion $B$.  This is locally Holder continuous for any exponent $\alpha < 1/2$.  Therefore we have, for $dt$ appropriately small, $$|M_{t+dt} - M_t| \leq C|\langle M \rangle_{t+dt} - \langle M \rangle_t|^\alpha = o(dt^{2 \alpha})$$

Comment: Instead of using Holder continuity, what happens if we use the actual modulus of continuity of the Brownian motion, which is $\sqrt{-2\delta \log(\delta)}$ for $\delta$ small enough? (So we use the tightest part of the bound) I suppose it still doesn't suffice.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a confusion in or abuse of notation. By the "Suppose ..." sentence, $dt$ is a positive "real" time step that should be written $\newcommand{\D}{\mathit{\Delta}}$ $\D t$ to make it different from the differential notation. The following equations are likewise about the differences $\D Z_\pi$ and $\D(Z_\pi^2)$. Then the Landau $o(\D t)$ is the truncation error of that formula (or the Euler-Maruyama method).

Comment: Yes that's correct (as far as I can interpret), so there is no confusion on my part as far as I can see right now.  I don't know how the author makes the conclusion though, which is what I'm asking about (i.e. why is $\int_t^{t+\Delta t} Z_s dZ_s - Z_t \Delta Z_t = o(dt)$?).  This is from a textbook (*Stochastic Portfolio Theory* by Fernholz on p. 130)

Comment: Yes, the first of these equations is exact, the error term is not necessary. Even with the discretized interpretation one has $Δ(Z_t)^2=Z_{t+dt}^2-Z_t^2=(Z_t+ΔZ_t)^2-Z_t^2=2Z_tΔZ_t+(ΔZ_t)^2$.