# Potential Local Martingale property derived from its quadratic variation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, local-martingales

Suppose we have a continuous local martingale $M$ such that $\langle M \rangle_t =o(t)$ - i.e. $$\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{\langle M \rangle_t}{t} = 0$$  Does this imply that $$\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{M_t}{t} = 0 $$ as well? i.e. is $M$ also $o(t)$ about $0$?  I am asking as a potential strategy to solve [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4173386/differential-in-itos-formula-and-little-o-notation)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127018/discussion-on-question-by-qp212223-potential-local-martingale-property-derived-f).

Comment: It seems this post is leading to some debate, which maybe should be moved to meta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"$ M $ may not be $ o(t) $", the following is an example. Let $ B=\{B_t,t\ge 0\} $ be the Brownian motion with $\langle B\rangle_t =t  $ and
\begin{equation*}
 M_t=B_{t^2}, \qquad t\ge 0.
\end{equation*}
Then $ M=\{M_t, t\ge 0\} $ is a continuous local martingale with $\langle M\rangle_t =t^2  $, hence
\begin{equation*}
 \lim_{t\to0}\frac{\langle M\rangle_t}{t}=0.
\end{equation*}
Meanwhile
\begin{equation*}
 \frac{|M_t|}{t}=\frac{|B_{t^2}|}{t}
 =\frac{|B_{t^2}|}{\sqrt{2t^2\log\log(1/t^2)}} \sqrt{2\log\log(1/t^2)}.
\end{equation*}
Using the LIL of BM at $ t=0 $ we have
\begin{equation*}
 \varlimsup_{t\to0}\frac{|M_t|}{t}=+\infty.
\end{equation*}

Comment: Thank you! I can only give the bounty in six hours so I will come back to award it when I can.  Cheers.

Comment: You are welcome, @qp212223.